# Stuff year gaps to show separte listings for gaps - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I have a column with sequence. I need to find the gaps in sequence and run stuff to create separate listings where gap occurs. I have created a cte with min and max to use with stuff.. I can't figure out how to identify gaps in sequence though. Please assist. Here is the same data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    sku varchar(50), 
    year float, 
    make varchar(50),  
    model varchar(50),
    model2 varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (sku, year, make, model, model2)
VALUES ('AVS1234', '2000',  'Xbox', 'pilot', 'ex'),
       ('AVS1234', '2001',  'Xbox', 'pilot', 'ex'),
       ('AVS1234', '2014',  'Xbox', 'pilot', 'ex');

WITH firstpass AS
(
    SELECT
        sku,
        MIN(year) AS min,
        MAX(year) AS max,
        make, model, model2
    FROM
        Table1
    GROUP BY
        sku, make, model, model2
)
SELECT 
    sku,
    CAST([min] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '-' + 
    CAST([max] AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + make + ' ' + model +
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + COALESCE([model2], '') + ''
           FROM firstpass 
           WHERE sku = a.sku
           FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS NamesList2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY sku asc) AS RowNum
FROM 
    firstpass AS a
GROUP BY 
    sku, [min], [max], make, model;

DROP TABLE table1
```

The intended result is

```
sku          Nameslist                  Row
-------------------------------------------
AVS1234      2000 - 2001 xbox Pilot ex  1
AVS1234      2014 xbox Pilot ex         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic Gaps and Islands with a little twist.

**Example**

```
Select SKU
      ,Nameslist = concat(
                   case when min(Year)<> max(Year) then concat(min(Year),' - ') end
                   ,max(year)
                   ,' '+max(make)
                   ,' '+max(model)
                   ,' '+max(model2)
                  )
 From (
         Select *
               ,Grp = Year - Row_Number() over (Partition by SKU order by Year)
          From  Table1
      ) A
 Group By SKU,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
SKU        Nameslist
AVS1234    2000 - 2001 Xbox pilot ex
AVS1234    2014 Xbox pilot ex
```

Comment: This is not working where range is missing a few sequences e.g. now the sequence is : 1997
1998
1999
1999
1999
1999
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2001
2001
2001
2002
2002
2002
2002
2003
2003
2003
2003

Comment: @Wsi Ah not missing there are dupelicate years.  Give me a minute to see what I can do

Comment: Data i am working with will have both duplicates and missing sequences.. I will await your reply. Thanks John

Comment: @Wsi Change Row_Numer() to Dense_Rank()

Comment: @Wsi Perhaps you can edit your question with a more robust sample.

Comment: @Wsi Here is an example with duplicate years  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2b7043ad541135280b007fda8b8dae95

Comment: made a modification to model 2. The query is not working as intended any more https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8e2a5ecd7774add79f5ffb9b8d99fb4c

Comment: with no model 2 the intended would split 2000 and 2001:   "2000 Xbox pilot"
   and "2001 Xbox pilot ex"

Comment: @Wsi Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=762f90c16f944951532aaa1e3266db63

Comment: I have another dataset here that required dense rank. SE Comfort submodel wont return proper values. The rest do. I cant quite figure out what's causing this. Please have a look. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a2e98dddcf36a77291cda226682e4a88

Comment: This is what i did : "Dense_Rank() over (Partition by [sku] order by n, model2 desc)" ... seems to work. Is this the proper way of handling this issue though?

Comment: jumped the gun there. "model2 desc" doesnt work either. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d8df29a1a6acf0cd3e578224d31b5f8a now se comfort is fine but the others are not. Please assist.

Comment: I also tried the other query you provided without dense rank. Unfortunately to no avail.